# Drupal Custom Module | How do I output all the fields of a node in a block

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-modules

I have a node that I want to output in a block, because the node can contain different kind of fields I don't want to specify the fields.

Can someone explain me how this can be done?

I tried this, but I just get a long list of notices without any output.

```
    function mymodule_block_view($delta = '') {
    $node = node_load(6);
    $node_content = node_view($node);

    switch($delta){
        case 'mymodule':
        $block['subject'] = t('title');   
        $block['content'] = theme('block', $node_content);  
    }
    return $block;
}
```

Thanks in advance!
Result: No content and a list of notices:

```
*Notice: Undefined index: #block in template_preprocess_block() (line 937 of /home/user/public_html/drupal/modules/block/block.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in template_preprocess_block() (line 939 of /home/user/public_html/drupal/modules/block/block.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in template_preprocess_block() (line 940 of /home/user/public_html/drupal/modules/block/block.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in template_preprocess_block() (line 943 of*
```

Comment: Hey, how about using hook_block instead and setting the block content to the node->content value, which is the already rendered version of the node.

Comment: FYI - There is a [nodeblock module](http://drupal.org/project/nodeblock) available.  _"This module allows you to specify content type(s) as being a block"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a result when I use the hook node.
I already tested the hook node before posting this question, but yeah, i don't know why it wasn't working then.

Don't know if this manner is the best/easiest way but I've got an output so I'm glad!

```
function mymodule_block_view($delta = '') {

    switch($delta){
        case 'mymodule':            
               $node_content = node_view(node_load(6));
               $content = theme('node', $node_content);

               $block = array(
                 'subject' => t('My Module'),
                 'content' => $content);
    }
    return $block;
}
```

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1) [node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_render/7) returns an array which needs to be rendered using [drupal_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_render/7)

2) You don't need to use theme('block') on this content.

If you want to pass the node's object to your `tepmlate_preprocess_block` and to your matching `theme` file, you can use this

```
case 'mymodule':
  $block['subject'] = t('title');   
  $block['#node'] = $node;
  $block['content'] = '';
```

Then, you can use whatever attribute of the node you want in your theming file, by accesing $block['#node'].

Comment: Thanks for the answer although I can't get any result:

1) I used drupal_render() but without any result.. doing something wrong I think
2) that's a path you take where I can't follow you. template_preprocess_block, does this mean the word 'template' needs to be replaced by your own modulename or is there an example or more documentation of giving custom variables to a certain function?

Comment: try not calling theme('block') inside this hook.